# Reopening class and adding method not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to add a method to the class `Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError` by reopening the class, but  `Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError.new("error message").error_message` shows `undefined` method `error_message`. I have added the below code in lib folder of rails application.

```
module SyntaxError
  def error_message
    "This is error message"
  end
end

Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError.include(SyntaxError)
```

If I run the same code (above one) in the console and call `Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError.new("error message").error_message` it works fine.

Comment: Check if the module is loaded when the app is starting.

Comment: require 'syntax_error' is returning true. 'syntax_error' is the file name within lib folder where i have added above code.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a name collision for the module name.
I've renamed it and it works:

```ruby
module SyntaxError2
  def error_message
    "This is error message"
  end
end

Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError.include(SyntaxError2)
```

Comment: I have tried that. It didn't work. Have you tried running Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError.new("error message").error_message in console.

Comment: https://github.com/kunashir/github_search/commit/4d91ed43824b97ef741d1427fa835403af77ad85 looks to this commit maybe it will helpful for you.

Comment: `SyntaxError` is the base class in Ruby.

Comment: after running require 'syntax_error2' it is working. Do you have any idea why we need to run require 'syntax_error2' in controller as per your above github ink.

Comment: Nokogiri::XML::SyntaxError.include(SyntaxError2) adding this line in syntax_error2.rb. Is this the right way.

Comment: I think we need `require`, because it has not loaded automatically but I am not sure how must it need to be done, it related to an autoloading mechanism.